# Mass assigning multiple self-joined new records at the same time with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a javascript form which allows users to create a hierarchy of categories underneath a parent object.

The hierarchy is created with a self-referential join thusly:

```
class DefaultCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "DefaultCategory", :inverse_of => :children
  has_many :children, :class_name => "DefaultCategory", :inverse_of => :parent
end
```

When this form gets submitted, I would like the "parent_id" field to be properly populated, however the parent may also be a new record and thus does not yet have an ID.

My attempt thus far looks like this once parsed into params:

```
{"default_categories_attributes"=>
  {"new_category_1"=>
    {"id"=>"", "parent_id"=>"", "name"=>"New Category 1"},
   "new_category_2"=>
    {"id"=>"", "parent_id"=>"new_category_1", "name"=>"New Category 2"},
   "new_category_3"=>
    {"id"=>"", "parent_id"=>"new_category_2", "name"=>"New Category 3 "},
   "new_category_4"=>
    {"id"=>"", "parent_id"=>"new_category_3", "name"=>"New Category 4"}
  }
}
```

Is it possible with mass assignment to have these new records correctly created and referencing one another? Possibly through nesting each child category into the "children_attributes" of their parent and getting the top level association id to replicate downward somehow?

Comment: `client.update_attributes "default_categories_attributes" => { "0" => { "name" => "george", "children_attributes" => { "1" => { "name" => "junior", "client_id" => client.id } } } }` Does work, but I would prefer not to be embedding the client id manually in all the nested objects on the form.

Comment: Using children_attributes falls apart when trying to re-assign one category to another parent.

Comment: I have abandoned the approach of trying to cram it into one form and switched to each action making a json call, live updating the model. It would be nice to know if the form approach could be made to work, however.